# Как сохранять таблицу для каждого пользователя индивидуально на js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Идея такая: есть три инпута и кнопка, пользователь вводит данные в инпуты нажимает на кнопку и джава скрипт добавляет данные в хтмл таблицу. Часть кода что добавляет в таблицу значения я уже сделал, но после перезагрузки страницы (либо закрытия браузера) все данные исчизают. Нужно чтобы таблица сохранялась индивидуально для каждого пользователя.Как это можно реализовать на js?
P.s: нужна инфа как это можно реализовать, а не сам код.

Comment: нужно подключать сервер

Comment: нужно для кождого пользователя бд создавать? или это като можно экономние сделать(не шарю в серверах)

Comment: для всех один, для каждого просто разная информация для таблицы)

Comment: смотрите в сторону node.js - сервер на javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял, то чтобы данные сохранялись, тебе нужно воспользоватся базой данных. Если это очень напряжно, то временно можешь воспользоватся localStorage. Где будешь сохранять данные в виде объектов.
Например (Схема localStorage):

```
localStorage[userId] = JSON.stringify({
    // Данные
})
```

А для того чтобы вывести данные людей в разных таблицах - перебери циклом localStorage и в JS создавай новый елемент DOM (table) и заполняй его инфой, ....

А вообще, изучи Vue или React или Angular - меньше проблем будет

Comment: Спасибо, пока буду разбираться с local storage можешь посоветовать конкретный фреймворк?

Comment: Мой совет - Vue. Он очень прост для начинания. Он создан из всего лучшего React & Angular

Comment: Да и у него очень хорошая документация

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону localStorage. Там вы можете хранить данные в JSON и обращаться к ним после перезагрузки страницы и даже закрытия браузера.

Пример:

Задать значение:

`localStorage.setItem('ключ', 'значение')`

Получить это значение:

`localStorage.getItem('ключ')`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать [куки](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) или [локальное хранилище](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) браузера.

Но самый эффективный и надежный способ будет работать с сервером. Т.е. отправлять данные на сервер(по Ajax или простой отправкой формы) и сохранять их в базе. Номер ячейки в базе сохраняется в тех же куки/сессиях или запоминается по IP и адресуется к данным в бд что пользователь ожидает увидеть.